# How can I get the response header error from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Using Laravel -

```
abort(403, 'This is an exception message.');
```

How can I access this message from my JavaScript?

```
// Get the project based on projectID.
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/projects/getProject/' + projectID
}).done(function(response){
    ProjectStore.getProjectSuccessful(response);
}).error(function(error){
    console.log(error)
});
```

My `error` object has a `statusText` property of 'Forbidden', and a `responseText` property that contains the entire HTML (in which I can see my error message) - but is there an easy way to access that message from my error object without parsing through the HTML?

Comment: `Forbidden` is an http error, errorcode 403. So you actually get your error - check if you have the correct permissions

Comment: My bad - I am using `abort(403, 'This is an exception message.')` - which is why it is showing 'Forbidden'. I'm still unsure of how to access the message itself without going through the HTML that is returned as response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the `abort()` function takes a third argument - an array - and this gets sent up through the response header.

So - updated code in PHP:

```
$error = 'User not authorized to view project.'; 
abort(401, $error, array('errorText'=>$error));
```

In my JavaScript:

```
// Get the project based on projectID.
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/projects/getProject/' + projectID
}).done(function(response){
    ProjectStore.getProjectSuccessful(response);
}).error(function(error){
    console.log(error.getResponseHeader('errorText'));
});
```